# Prove $p(M' ∪ M'') = p(M') ∪ p(M'')$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a problem regarding mappings and sets that I'm stuck with. The problem follows as:

Let $M$, $M'$, $M''$, $N$, $N'$, $N''$ be sets and let $p: M → N$, $m → p(m)$ be a map.

Prove:  $M'$, $M'' ⊂ M ⇒ p(M' ∪ M'') = p(M') ∪ p(M'')$

How do I tackle this problem? My class is strictly taught in German so I can't really use the resources given to it's full potential.

Comment: Double inclusion?

Comment: I'm more so confused by the mapping, but yea I get that I should use double inclusion @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 0):

The sets $p(M'\cup M'')$ and $p(M')\cup p(M'')$ are defined as follows:
\begin{align}
p(M'\cup M'')&=\{p(m)\in N| m\in M'\cup M'' \}\\
p(M')\cup p(M'')&=\{p(m)\in N| m\in M'\}\cup\{p(m)\in N|m\in M''\}
\end{align}
Let $n_1\in p(M'\cup M'')$ be any element. That implies $\exists m_1\in M'\cup M''$ such that $p(m_1)=n_1$. Note that at least one of the following must be true: $m_1\in M'$, $m_1\in M''$. Assume without loss of generality that $m_1\in M'$. Then $p(m_1)=n_1\in P(M')\subseteq p(M')\cup p(M'')$. This part concludes that $p(M'\cup M'')\subseteq p(M')\cup p(M'')$.

Similarly, given $n_2\in p(M')\cup p(M'')$ we can assume without loss of generality that $n_2\in P(M')$ which implies $\exists m_2\in M'$ such that $p(m_2)=n_2$. Therefore, $n_2\in p(M'\cup M'')$. This part concludes that $p(M')\cup p(M'')\subseteq p(M'\cup M'')$.

And we get the desired equality from what we showed
\begin{equation*}
p(M'\cup M'')\subseteq p(M')\cup p(M'')\\
p(M')\cup p(M'')\subseteq p(M'\cup M'')\\
\implies p(M'\cup M'')=p(M')\cup p(M'')
\end{equation*}

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1849052)

Comment: @Armandoj18eos I've updated the answer.